# Как правильно парсить json в java

Tags: java, json, retrofit, gson

Как средствами google-gson можно реализовать парсинг этого json?

```
{
"status":"ok",
"data":[
{
"title":"New1",
"text":"text 1",
"text2":"category 1"
},
{
"title":"New2",
"text":"text 2",
"text2":"category 2"
},
{....
```

класс констант

```
public class Constants {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "ссылка/";
}
```

апи

```
public interface Api {

    @GET("api/videos.json")
    void getObject(Callback<String> object);
}
```

парсинг

```
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

        Object object= new Object.Builder()
                .setCategory(object.getString("title"))
                .setPrice(object.getString("text"))
                .setPrice(object.getString("text2"))
                .build();

        mListener.onFetchProgress(object);

    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    mListener.onFetchFailed();
}
```

Comment: Этот сайт предназначен для вопросов на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Streletz, перевёл вопрос, хотелось бы и решение по нему =)

Comment: @nskomega Если решили задать вопрос, то опишите подробно проблему или удалите его вовсе. В таком виде наберете минусов и вопрос в конце-концов удалят.

Comment: `JSONParser` подойдет?

Comment: @ВОРОН, вы имеете в виду json.parser.online.fr ?

Comment: Вот туториалы http://java-help.ru/retrofit-library/ http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-retrofit-tutorial/

Comment: @nskomega, нет, в `java` уже есть класс `JSONParser`

Comment: @Александр, в SE?

Comment: @Nofate, прекрасная библиотека `org.json`

Comment: @Александр, но это не "в Java"

Comment: Использую Retrofit и google-gson, вывожу в лог что спарсил, но отсечь первую часть  {"status":"ok", "data":[ {      не могу...

Comment: @Nofate, а где?

Comment: @Александр, когда говорят "в java уже есть класс", обычно, имеется в виду в стандартной библиотеке Java, а не в сторонних.

Comment: Да и ТС явно говорит про google-gson

Comment: @Nofate, пардон, не правильно сформулировал )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### При использовании Retrofit в качестве загрузчика:

1.Класс описывающий данные с сервера

```
class Dto {
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<Data> dataList;
    public static class Data {
        private String title;
        private String text;
        private String text2;
    }
}
```

2.Interface Api

```
@GET("api/videos.json")
void getObject(Callback<Dto> object);
```

3.В колбеке получаете готовый класс Dto с заполнеными полями из json

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        final String json = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"data\":[{\"title\":\"New1\",\"text\":\"text 1\",\"text2\":\"category 1\"},{\"title\":\"New2\",\"text\":\"text 2\",\"text2\":\"category 2\"}]}";
        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        final String status = jsonObject.getString("status");
        final JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
        final int size = jsonArray.length();
        final List<Map<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(size);
        Map<String, String> map;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            final JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("title", data.getString("title"));
            map.put("text", data.getString("text"));
            map.put("text2", data.getString("text2"));
            dataList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: С Map это пример, вставте свой класс dto вместо Map